# firebase storage: uploading jpg casuing Could not load the default credentials. on Node.js

Tags: firebase-storage

```
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase-admin/app");
const { getStorage } = require("firebase-admin/storage");

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "ajsoidjof",
  authDomain: "asodijfo",
  projectId: "sihfiasd",
  storageBucket: "sadjofjosad",
  messagingSenderId: "2039023423",
  appId: "saoijdofijo3ijo2",
  measurementId: "sijdofijeadsf",
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


  const bucket = getStorage().bucket();
  bucket.upload("./1.jpg");
```

This causes `Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.` error. And, how can I upload the `1.jpg` to just the main storage folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Firebase **Admin** SDK for Node.js, but then trying to initialize it with the configuration data for a client-side SDK. That won't work, so you'll either have to initialize the Admin SDK as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#node.js_1) or use the [client-side Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node).